# Need help working out how to add better image titles for a html/css slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website and I am trying to create an image slider with text associated with the image. The only thing I wanted to know is how to set up each image with an associated title that shows when you mouse over or hover the image, but i would like to have each image have a caption that flows with it in the slider. any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!
My Current code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5/CSS3 Responsive Image Slider</title>
<style type="text/css">
#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 2800%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: 135s slider infinite;
}
#slider figure img {
    float: left;
    width: 3.57%;
}
@keyframes slider {
    0%         {left: 0%;}
    1.78%      {left: 0%;}
    3.56%      {left: -100%;}
    5.34%      {left: -100%;}
    7.12%      {left: -200%;}
    8.90%      {left: -200%;}
    10.68%     {left: -300%;}
    12.46%     {left: -300%;}
    14.24%     {left: -400%;}
    16.02%     {left: -400%;}
    17.80%     {left: -500%;}
    19.58%     {left: -500%;}
    21.36%     {left: -600%;}
    23.14%     {left: -600%;}
    24.92%     {left: -700%;}
    26.70%     {left: -700%;}
    28.48%     {left: -800%;}
    30.26%     {left: -800%;}
    32.04%     {left: -900%;}
    33.82%     {left: -900%;}
    35.60%     {left: -1000%;}
    37.38%     {left: -1000%;}
    39.16%     {left: -1100%;}
    40.94%     {left: -1100%;}
    42.72%     {left: -1200%;}
    44.50%     {left: -1200%;}
    46.28%     {left: -1300%;}
    48.06%     {left: -1300%;}
    49.84%     {left: -1400%;}
    51.62%     {left: -1400%;}
    53.40%     {left: -1500%;}
    55.18%     {left: -1500%;}
    56.96%     {left: -1600%;}
    58.74%     {left: -1600%;}
    60.52%     {left: -1700%;}
    62.30%     {left: -1700%;}
    64.08%     {left: -1800%;}
    65.86%     {left: -1800%;}
    67.64%     {left: -1900%;}
    69.42%     {left: -1900%;}
    71.20%     {left: -2000%;}
    72.98%     {left: -2000%;}
    74.76%     {left: -2100%;}
    76.54%     {left: -2100%;}
    78.32%     {left: -2200%;}
    80.10%     {left: -2200%;}
    81.88%     {left: -2300%;}
    83.66%     {left: -2300%;}
    85.44%     {left: -2400%;}
    87.22%     {left: -2400%;}
    89.00%     {left: -2500%;}
    90.78%     {left: -2500%;}
    92.56%     {left: -2600%;}
    94.34%     {left: -2600%;}
    97.90%     {left: -2700%;}
    100.0%     {left: -2700%;}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider">
        <figure>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FRSxXro.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bum7YtT.png" title="This recipe was added as a end game way of obtaining Heart Dust">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lPg9AZR.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mIzEUcO.png" title="This recipe was added to resolve a recipe conflict">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QjS8TmB.png" title="This recipe was added to create a reliable way of obtaing heart crystal shards">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Z1KdPWr.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k3xAQdm.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sEXI5oi.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qBerwFJ.png" title="Since it can be hard to explore at times this recipe was added as an alternative to the traditional recipe">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pKhIeZI.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to community stating it made mass storage too easy to obtain">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FROcXX1.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its use in crafting extra hearts/lives">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/boQSDsB.png" title="This crafting recipe was added for endgame base building and recipes">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lUH0VEG.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DuczUCb.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was marginally reduced due to scarcity of resources">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/exrzspr.png" title="This recipe was added for the item to be used as a step in crafting extra lives/hearts">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eZklzjN.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dSOH45b.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SzSGpMn.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tXM9QPi.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0r4fykM.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MI5xrJt.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LV21qhi.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oG4CnV1.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zYdoMw6.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AP9FNTc.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its use in crafting extra hearts/lives">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OHWT31s.png" title="This recipe was added as an early game way of obtaining heart dust">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9kBcp9F.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FRSxXro.png" title="The crafting cost of this item was increased due to its power">
        </figure>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a div which will have a img and span that will be set asa slide for the slider like this

```
<figure>
<div class="sliderMain">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/SzSGpMn.png" title="This recipe was added because of the lack of appropriate parent mod">
          <div class="captionStyling"> your caption content </div>

...

</figure>

Respectively do put all the images in this type of layout
```

You can set the div to position bottom after the image or make the caption Div position any where on the image

Set this style to the div

```
#slider figure div {
    float: left;
    width: 3.57%;
}
```

As you see the layout then style the image and caption accordingly

Comment: would <div class="sliderMain"> be used in place of  <div id="slider"> ?

Comment: No place the div inside the figure and make this repeat for all the images